# JavaScript regex to search between strings

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi I would like to search between strings using regex for JavaScript

String format:

```
saobjectid=tt-234,ou=info
saobjectid=bb-456,ou=info
saobjectid=bng,ou=info
saobjectid=asx 1 ert 7,ou=info
```

Expected output:

```
tt-234
bb-456
bng
asx 1 ert 7
```

I have tried this

```
[a-z]+[-,\s]+[0-9]+
```

But didn't manage to capture all different scenarios

Thanks for your help

Comment: You can use `split()` for that like `str.split(/[=,]/)[1]`

Comment: Try `s.match(/=([^,=]*),/)[1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just added this answer to depict that it can also be done using `substr` in javascript:

```js
var a = "saobjectid=tt-234,ou=info";
var b = "saobjectid=bb-456,ou=info";
var c = "saobjectid=bng,ou=info";
var d = "saobjectid=asx 1 ert 7,ou=info";

console.log(getSubstr(a));
console.log(getSubstr(b));
console.log(getSubstr(c));
console.log(getSubstr(d));

function getSubstr(a){
    return a.substr(a.indexOf('=')+1, a.indexOf(',') - a.indexOf('=')-1);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

a regex like `=([-\s\w]+),` will do.

Check it out at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/RGnOT6/1) or here:

```js
var s=`saobjectid=tt-234,ou=info
saobjectid=bb-456,ou=info
saobjectid=bng,ou=info
saobjectid=asx 1 ert 7,ou=info"`;
var regexp =  /=([-\s\w]+),/g;
while ((match = regexp.exec(s)) != null){
  console.log(match[1]);
}
```